# How to change an existing AWS VPC resource with Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have just created a vpc on AWS with ansible like so:

```
- name: Ensure VPC is present
  ec2_vpc:
    state: present
    region: "{{ ec2_region }}"
    cidr_block: "{{ ec2_subnet }}"
    subnets:
      - cidr: "{{ ec2_subnet }}"
    route_tables:
      - subnets:
          - "{{ ec2_subnet }}"
        routes:
          - dest: 0.0.0.0/0
            gw: igw
    internet_gateway: yes # we want our instances to connect internet
    wait: yes # wait for the VPC to be in state 'available' before returning
    resource_tags: { Name: "my_project", environment: "production", tier: "DB" } # we tag this VPC so it will be easier for us to find it later
```

Note that this task is called from another playbook that takes care of filling the variables. 
Also note that I am aware the `ec2_vpc` module is deprecated and I should update this piece of code soon.
But I think those points are not relevant to the question.

So you can notice in the `resource_tags` I have a name for that project. When I first ran this playbook, I did not have a name. 
The VPC got created successfully the first time but then I wanted to add a name to it. So I tried adding it in the play, without knowing exactly how Ansible would know I want to update the existing VPC.
Indeed Ansible created a new VPC and did not update the existing one.

So the question is, how do I update the already existing one instead of creating a new resource?

Comment: Exactly such issues are the crux of "sales" pitches for Terraform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a conversation on the ansible irc (can't remember the usernames, sorry) it appears this specific module is not good at updating resources.

It looks like the answer lies in the new ec2_vpc_net module, specifically with the option multi_ok which by default won't duplicate VPCs with the same name and CIDR blocks.

docs: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vpc_net_module.html#ec2-vpc-net